# R mean difference of time period and per group

Tags: r, dplyr

my data looks like the following:

```
           Land happy gincdif uempla year
    1 Austria     8       2      0 2012
    2 Austria     4       1      0 2002
    3 Austria     7       2      0 2009
    4 Germany     9       4      0 2008
    5 Germany     9       4      0 2002
    6 Germany     5       1      0 2010
```

I already calculated the mean of happy per year and Land, using dplyr:

```
   DG <- dgf %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      mutate(mean.ha = mean(happy, na.rm=T))
```

Now I would like to calculate the difference of mean.ha between 2008 and 2010. I tried this code:

```
    DG <- dgf %>%
       group_by(year) %>%
       mutate(mean.ha = mean(happy, na.rm=T)) %>%
       mutate(diff.ha = mean.happy[year==2010] - 
       mean.happy[year==2008])
```

But I only get NA in the rows. Maybe it is because not for every Land exist observations in the years 2008 and 2012.

Does anyone have a solution for me? I want to calculate the decline of happiness for this time period.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The grouping has to be by "Land" instead of "year" otherwise you can only access the values within the same year-group, i.e. no comparison between groups

Comment: What do you want to do about the `gincdif` variable? This causes duplicate Land/year combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
dgf = data.frame(year = c(2008,2009,2010,2011), 
                 happy = c(1,0,0,1))

DG <- dgf %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(mean.ha = mean(happy, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  .[.$year == 2008 | .$year == 2010, "mean.ha"] %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  diff()
```